# "Removing" .html from the end of site address

Tags: html, web, admin

I want people to be able to type in this:

```
http://www.example.com/store
```

Instead of, say... this:

```
http://www.example.com/store.html
```

Is there some file somewhere that I can change so the user is redirected the "non-.html" address to the .html one? I would imagine that users would much rather type in the "non-.html" address than the other one.

I have full access to the site, so whatever needs to be changed can be changed. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: If you are on a LAMP server, research .htaccess files

Comment: this question is simply too broad unless you specify what your framework and server are.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know specifics. Very new to site admin stuff, but I guess it's a LAMP server as I do have a .htaccess file. Got it fixed either way, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it. You are looking at "URL Rewriting" in .htaccess file. There are many different techniques for doing it. Have a look at this [example](http://sicanstudios.com/post/17713225206/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works like a charm. Much better than jumping through directory hoops for every page!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.example.com/store/index.html would be one solution. If you visit example.com/store, your browser would automatically load the index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Google/Bing URL Rewriting within the context of the framework and web server you are using. This is a very large topic since every framework/server combination has a different way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using a web framework, or you don't know what an .htaccess file is, the simplest way might be to do it with directories.  If you create a root-level directory named "store" and move store.html into it as index.html, like this:

```
/
--store/
----index.html <- used to be "store.html"
```

then the url `http://site.com/store` should work like you want it to.